# In CakePHP 3, how to create a second-order belongsTo relationship?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.x

Let's say that I have a `cities` table with a `state_id` field, and a `states` table with a `country_id` field, as well as a `countries` table that the `country_id` field points to. So in CakePHP terms, `Cities belongsTo States`, and `States belongsTo Countries`.

Without altering the tables themselves, how do I make it so that for all intents and purposes, `States belongsTo Countries`? In other words, what do I need to put in my table models to make it so that I can do:

```
$cityArray = $this->Cities->find('all', [ 'contain' => 'Countries' ])->toArray();
```

and have it return an array of `Cities`, each of which contains a `Country`, without having `State` contained in the array?

Right now I'm editing the array post-query to remove `State` and splice `Country` back onto the `City`, but I'm wondering if there's a more transparent way to do it.

Comment: I think the closest you'll get would be doing $this->Cities->find()->contain(['States' => ['Countries']])

Comment: without creating a relation to states how would it know that it is related to country in turn, you can only play with fields in this case so that the states do not turn up, but for the relations you need to include the states. But for the relations to be maintained at least state.id and state.country_id needs to be pulled otherwise things won't work as desired.